# questions on descarte planning, meaning of orient_increment

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I wonder what is the meaning of ***orient_increment*** in ***AxialSymmetricPt***? On its class [reference](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/descartes_trajectory/html/classdescartes__trajectory_1_1AxialSymmetricPt.html#details), it shows

```
> orient_increment  (in radians, discretization of space [-Pi, Pi])
```

But what does discretization mean here?  My understanding is that it discretize [-Pi,Pi], like [-pi, -pi+0.01,-pi+0.02,....,pi-0.01,pi]. Is this right?

I was following the descarte tutorial, it used this helper function

```
descartes_core::TrajectoryPtPtr makeTolerancedCartesianPoint(const Eigen::Affine3d& pose)
{
    using namespace descartes_core;
    using namespace descartes_trajectory;
  return TrajectoryPtPtr( new AxialSymmetricPt(pose, // Nominal pose
                                               M_PI/2.0, // Search discretization
                                               AxialSymmetricPt::Z_AXIS) ); // Free axis
}
```

I wonder what does the M_PI/2 means.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265552/questions-on-descarte-planning,-meaning-of-orient_increment/) by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are correct in your thinking.   In the cited example the discretization is specified as increments of pi/2 (90 degrees).  M_PI is a constant for pi from the math library math.h

---

Originally posted by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) with karma: 525 on 2017-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on 2017-07-06**:
Thank you for your reply. I'm kind of curious why is pi/2 is enough? Does pi/2 apply to the joints?

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2017-07-06**:
Pi/2 is arbitrary in this case and in my experience not enough.   This is the discretization about the specified free axis in terms of tool/frame poses (i.e., Cartesian and not joint angles).  Ultimately it is a trade-off between search resolution and planning time.

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2017-07-06**:
I usually start with pi/16 and adjust from there but it will be application dependant in the end

**Comment by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on 2017-07-06**:
Thank you. I'm going to try it with different values to see what's the difference. Thank you for your reply.

Also, I wonder if you know some moveit examples with good documents available?

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2017-07-06**:
For just moveit there are good ones on their wiki [here](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/).  For Descartes, there is less.   You can start [here](http://wiki.ros.org/descartes/Tutorials)